# Criar um gráfico pizza com html e angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html5

Gostaria de saber como faço para criar um gráfico (ex: pizza) a partir dos dados de um array com html e angularjs. Um exemplo ajudaria bastante. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Relacionada: [Criar um gráfico pizza com html e angularjs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/232421/criar-um-gr%C3%A1fico-pizza-com-html-e-angularjs/232431#232431)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a biblioteca [`Angular Chart`](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) para fazer o que deseja. Coloquei um exemplo simples.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app', ['chart.js']);

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('GraficoController', GraficoController);

  GraficoController.$inject = [];

  function GraficoController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.grafico = {};
    vm.grafico.descricoes = ['Carros', 'Motos', 'Lanchas'];
    vm.grafico.valores = [3, 1, 8];
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.0.1/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chart.js/1.1.1/angular-chart.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="GraficoController as vm" style="height: 50%; width: 50%">
    <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="vm.grafico.valores" chart-labels="vm.grafico.descricoes">
    </canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

Existem outras bibliotecas citadas [**nesta resposta do SOen (How can i make bar & pie charts in angular js)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186664/3388148):

1. [Angular charts usando D3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3);
2. [Angular-nvD3](https://developers.google.com/chart/);
3. Você pode utilizar o [Google Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30186664/3388148) em conjunto com o AngularJS.

Comment: Sorack, testei aqui e funcionou. Esse gráfico simples já resolveria meu problema, pq estou fazendo um protótipo. A questão é que no momento em que o gráfico vai sendo criado, ao enconstar o mouse ele ilumina uma das partes do gráfico e para, gerando erros em seguida. Queria saber também pq as labels não aparecem ao enconstar o mouse. Grato!

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola baixa a biblioteca e deixa ela junto com os seus fontes que funcionará

Comment: Funcionou. Muito obrigado!